# Dynamically assigning hibernate connection url

Tags: hibernate, url, connection, dynamically-generated

Iam editing this post: I was trying to "databaseUrl" from another class DbDriverManager but its giving me error, if you see my code where creating settion factory block is  static   { } i think this making issue. Can you please suggest me better way

iam hetting this error : Could not initialize class com.xxx.YY.hn.util.HibernateUtil

SessionFactory initial creation error.java.lang.NullPointerException
this is my code :

```
public class DbDriverManager {


public String databaseUrl;

public String getDatabaseUrl() {
    return databaseUrl;
}

public void setDatabaseUrl() {
    FacesContext context = javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    this.databaseUrl = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("databaseUrl");
}
```

}

```
public class HibernateUtil
```

{

```
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  static 
  {    //create sessionFactory only once    
    try 
    {

        Configuration cfg = null;
        DbDriverManager dm = new DbDriverManager();

        dm.setDatabaseUrl();

      // creating the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        cfg =    new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();

        System.out.println("dm.getDatabaseUrl() :" + dm.getDatabaseUrl());

        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", dm.getDatabaseUrl());
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "wf_dbo");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "webflex");            
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        cfg.configure();

        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        //sessionFactory = new cfg.buildSessionFactory();
      //sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();


    } 
    catch (Throwable ex) 
    {
           System.out.println("SessionFactory initial creation error."+ ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }
  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
     return sessionFactory;
  }
```

}

Comment: Your code snippet seem to have answered your own question. Maybe you should explain to us what problem you had with those

Comment: Can you please check code now, i edited previous one

Comment: Can anybody help on this please

Answer (score 2):

Your code need to be altered little bit as shown below

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(String ip) {

        SessionFactory sf = null;
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://" + ip + ":3306/dbName");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        return sf;
    }
```

Don't call empty argumented configure(). I hope it looks for hibernate.cfg.xml in default classpath.

For the more, AnnotationConfiguration() is deprecated. Please use hibernate 4.3 or above.
Above code is for hibernate 4.3.6

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the leading `"hibernate."` in the names, which aren't there in `context.xml`